# There's a simple logic error in my JS that I lack the knowledge to find

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Unit 2 Graded Exercise 1
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Unit 2 Graded Exercise 1</h1>
    <br/>
  </header>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="price" id="label">Purchase Price</label>
      <input type="text" id="partPrice" />
      <button type="button" id="button">Calculate Shipping and Handling</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  var partPrice = document.getElementById("partPrice").value;
  var totalPrice;

  function calcTotal() {
    if (partPrice <= 25) {
      var totalPrice = partPrice + 1.5; //price + sh
    } else if (partPrice > 25) {
      var totalPrice = (partPrice * 0.10) + partPrice; //10% of price as sh + price
    }
    alert("Shipping and Handling is $" + totalPrice);
  }
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
  if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
  } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
    submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

So my goal is to show interest + $1.50 for a total cost below or equal to $25 and 10% interest of a total cost above $25. My problem is that the "partPrice", which is the price that the user enters, is not being received. I've looked up quite a bit about this and I've seen people go around by creating multiple variables to pick up certain values but I have yet to understand why. I would really like an explanation because, going through this code, it all looks logically correct. I'm really lost as to where I should be changing my syntax.

Comment: In your script, try putting the partPrice assignment inside the click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your code to following

- Move the get value code inside the function
- Convert the value which is a string to a number

  ```
   function calcTotal() {
       var partPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("partPrice").value);
       ...
  }
  ```

Comment: This worked. Can you explain why for me? Why would the input from the user need to be inside the function? Is it because of local versus global or am I missing something?

Comment: @River - Once you click on the button, you will need the latest value to be used for calculation. However, if you only have defined it outside the function, it will take the initial value and will never be updated i.e. irrespective of the value in the input box, computation will always be against the initial value.

Comment: Thank you! Good to know that everything that happens inside a function is local. It would have taken me ages to find out.

Comment: Please see that you can anytime change the value of variables defined outside the function. You can refer to MDN for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just get data inside function. also remove variable declaration in `if` statement

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Unit 2 Graded Exercise 1
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Unit 2 Graded Exercise 1</h1>
    <br/>
  </header>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="price" id="label">Purchase Price</label>
      <input type="text" id="partPrice" />
      <button type="button" id="button">Calculate Shipping and Handling</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  var partPrice,
    totalPrice;

  function calcTotal() {
    partPrice = document.getElementById("partPrice").value;
    if (partPrice <= 25) {
      totalPrice = partPrice + 1.5; //price + sh
    } else if (partPrice > 25) {
      totalPrice = (partPrice * 0.10) + partPrice; //10% of price as sh + price
    }
    alert("Shipping and Handling is $" + totalPrice);
  }
  var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
  if (submitButton.addEventListener) {
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
  } else if (submitButton.attachEvent) {
    submitButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var partPrice = document.getElementById("partPrice").value;
```

This line is executed once when the script is loaded, so `partPrice` will be an empty string. It doesn't get reevaluated automatically when you write anything in input, so you'll have to call `document.getElementById("partPrice").value` again in `calcTotal` to fetch the current value of `partPrice`.